# Jquery Conditional Logic - How can I click a button if a span has a particular sibling?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```
<a class="item">
    <span class="item_label">BIG_1</span>
    <span class="acitve-high">...</span>
</a>
<a class="item">
    <span class="item_label">BIG_2</span>
    <span class="acitve-low">...</span>
</a>

<a class="button-high">...</a>
<a class="button-low">...</a>
```

How can I achieve the following actions using jquery function?

If the span containing text "BIG_1" has a sibling with class name "active-high" then click button with class name "button-high"
else if span containing text "BIG_1" has a sibling with class name "active-low" then click button with class name "button-low"

In the HTML, the span with text BIG_1 currently has a sibling with class name "active-high". I want the code to always check if this is true and then click a button with class name "button-high" if so. The website is dynamic and so the span with class name "active-high" sometimes automatically changes to "active-low". So, I want the code to click the button with class name "active-low" instead every time this change occurs.

Please note: More than one span has the class name "item_label" so I can't use the class name to identify the span with text BIG_1. Also, I can't use its position either because that changes automatically from time to time as well.

Comment: Not sure i understand your question. Do you want the code to automatic click on the `button-high` or `button-low`? and how should this code be triggered, by page load or?

Comment: "In the html, the span with text BIG_1 currently has a sibling with class name "active-high". I want the code to always check if this is true and then click a button with class name "button-high" if so. The website is dynamic and so the span with class name "active-high" sometimes automatically changes to "active-low". So, I want the code to click the button with class name "active-low" instead every time this change occurs.

Answer (score 0):

```
var big1_siblings = $('span:contains("BIG_1")').siblings();

for (var i = 0; i < big1_siblings.length; i++) {
  if ($(big1_siblings[i]).hasClass('acitve-high')) {
    $('.button-high').trigger("click");
    break;
  } else if ($(big1_siblings[i]).hasClass('acitve-low')) {
    $('.button-low').trigger("click");
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.